# Why CMake/make give different output despite unchanged source code?

Tags: c++, cmake

### Introduction

Hello all,

I'm writing C++ and trying to wrap my head around CMake.

The idea is this: opening a file and checking if it's open.

I have two files in my `src/` folder, a `main.cpp` and `hello.txt` which contains some text. Tree structure:

```
- CMakeLists.txt
- src/
  ├── CMakeLists.txt
  ├── hello.txt
  └── main.cpp
```

I also have a CMakeLists.txt at the same level of `src/`.

The code is quite simple in `main.cpp`:

```
int main()
{
    std::ifstream file;

    file.open("./hello.txt");

    std::cout << "File is open? " << file.good() << std::endl;
    file.close();

    return 0;
}
```

And when I compile this manually using `g++` within the src folder (`g++ main.cpp -o main`), I don't have any issues, the output shows: `File is open? 1` so it was indeed open.

### Problems using CMake

The problem arose when I tried using CMake to build, configure and compile this little project. I'm not entirely sure yet how to write proper CMakeLists.txt files. But with the most basic of CMake instructions, the output I received was: `File is open? 0`.

Here's the code in my root CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(fileio)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_subdirectory(src)

add_executable(main src/main.cpp)
```

I hadn't changed the file locations, and the output was changed. Maybe I didn't include all of the files using CMake so I used the `add_subdirectory()` directive and I also had to put another CMakeLists.txt file in the `src/` folder. I left that latter empty because I don't consider this folder a library.

### Checking compile commands

I thought the problem was the compiling command so I added the `-DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON` directive to CMake when building my project. Here's the output of the `compile_commands.json`:

```
[
{
  "directory": "path/to/files/build",
  "command": "/usr/bin/g++ -std=gnu++14 -o CMakeFiles/main.dir/src/main.cpp.o -c path/to/files/src/main.cpp",
  "file": "path/to/files/src/main.cpp"
}
]
```

To me, it doesn't seem far remote from my initial `g++ main.cpp -o main`. But I don't understand why the file doesn't open when I use the Makefile generated by CMake.

### My Question

Did I miss certain commands or variables to set in the CMakeLists.txt file to include the hello.txt file to the executable?

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default initializing them and immediately overwriting the default values. In this case that means changing `std::ifstream file; file.open(“./hello.txt”);` to `std::ifstream file(“./hello.txt”);`. Also, you don’t need to call `file.close();`. The destructor will do that.

Comment: The difference is that CMake creates an executable file in the **build tree**, not in the same directory as the source file. See the duplicate question about placing the text file and executable into the same directory. Alternatively, you may run your program from the directory with the text file.

Comment: @PeteBecker thanks for the tip, actually I made it that way on purpose, but I know the better way is initializing variables immediately. I'll do as you indicated from now on, thanks!

Comment: @Tsyvarev The last advice works perfectly, for small projects that is, like the one I have now, thanks. But for large projects that need interaction between several files, this may not be ideal. I may open a new discussion for that topic.

Comment: @hobyr: If you know another solution for the duplicate question, then you are free to add an answer to it.